# Javascript comparing window.pageYOffset strange logic

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain why this statement is falsy?

Comment: Please don't post links to paintings of code. Post the code itself.

Comment: because a picture can't run code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `window.pageYoffset` instead of `window.pageYOffset`, with a capital "O" so the statement evaluates to

```js
undefined < 708.640625 + 0 // false
```